# Larger branch of a tree

Tags: list, haskell, tree, nodes

If I have the data type:

```
data Tree t = Leaf | Branch t t
```

How can I make a function to get the longest branch of a tree? I want to get the answer in a list, that contains all the values of the nodes of the longest branch, from the root, to the leaf. Something like this:

```
longestBranch :: (Tree a) -> [a]
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? could you implement the algorithm in another language or would this be also a problem?

Comment: Also note that the type you have defined is not a tree.

Comment: @moondaisy At least the type in the question is a legal type! Yours doesn't give enough type arguments to `Tree`.

Comment: You probably wanted `data Tree t = Leaf | Branch (Tree t) t (Tree t)`. With `data Tree t = Leaf | Branch (Tree t) (Tree t)` your question doesn't really work (unless you meant get a list of elements, all of which are equally deep at maximum depth).

Answer (score 4):

[As amalloy noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800699/larger-branch-of-a-tree#comment80548615_46800699) the type you currently have in your question is not a tree:

```
data Tree t = Leaf | Branch t t
```

This is isomorphic to `Maybe (t,t)` - it either contains two `t` values, or nothing.

The two most common binary trees that people define either have values at the branches:

```
       A
     /   \
    B     C
   / \   / \
  D   * *   E
 / \       / \
*   F     *   G
   / \       / \
  *   *     *   *
```

Or at the leaves:

```
       *
     /   \
    *     *
   / \   / \
  *   3 4   *
 / \       / \
0   *     5   *
   / \       / \
  1   2     6   7
```

Since you're looking for something that "contains all the values of the nodes
of the longest branch from the root to [a] leaf", I'm assuming you're looking
for the former.

This datatype can be defined as:

```
data Tree t = Leaf | Branch (Tree t) t (Tree t)
```

A `Leaf` is a height-0 tree. A `Branch` contains two subtrees and a value.

Now, looking at the type of the desired function

```
longestBranch :: Tree a -> [a]
```

We can break it down into two cases by the type:

```
longestBranch Leaf = _
longestBranch (Branch left value right) = 
  let longestLeft = longestBranch left
      longestRight = longestBranch right
  in _
```

Now for some leading questions:

- What is the longest branch starting at a `Leaf`?
- Given that `longestLeft` is the longest branch for the `left` subtree, and
  that `longestRight` is the longest branch for the `right` subtree, can you
  determine what the longest branch for `Branch left value right` is?

Comment: [SPOILER] Once you've solved this version, you should be able to improve performance by keeping track of the lists' lengths yourself.